# Application crashing after boot

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I'm creating an android application that requires to be started at boot time, I do everything needed to achieve so, but when the device boots it just crashes. If I manually open the app after that it opens normally: it only crashes when the device has just started not if the user opens it manually.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
package="com.example.remind" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmGenerator"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.remind.STOP" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.remind.START" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

AlarmGenerator.java

```
public class AlarmGenerator extends BroadcastReceiver {

private AlarmManager alarm;
private PendingIntent send;

public AlarmGenerator() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Reminder.class);
    send = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        Intent start = new Intent(context, MainMenu.class);
        start.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainMenu.class));
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals("com.example.remind.STOP")){
        alarm.cancel(send);
    }else {
        start();
    }
}

private void start(){
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + ((1000 * 30) * 1), (30 * 1000) * 1, send);
    }
}
```

I searched for other answers and they were about misspelled classes and things like that, but this just appears to crash for no reason (but there has to be one). IDK if it matters but I am targeting API 16 and the minimum SDK version is also 16, in another project I did something similar but I started a service not an Activity but the minimum SDK version was 7 (Gingerbread) and the target 16 (Jelly Bean).

Comment: when you say crash, is it the ANR or a force close?

Comment: Post your logcat content

Comment: It just displays a message saying "Reminder has stopped working"  my phone is in Spanish so I don't know the exact message in English.

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Remove some code here and there, and see if the problem still persists. And as @TonyChhabada said, post the relevant logcat.

Comment: How do I get the logcat if the device disconnects when I restart it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably see in logcat as below;

"Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

So, Replace your code as follows.

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
    Intent start = new Intent(context, MainMenu.class);
    start.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
-        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainMenu.class));
+        context.startActivity(start);
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals("com.example.remind.STOP")){
```

Comment: Umm I already did that. It's in the code I showed. I saw an example earlier so I added that but it still didn't work.

Comment: why do you create new instance of Intent when calling startActivity() rather than "start" you already have created? If calling startActivity() outside of an Activity you should set flag of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in intent, but in your code you dont use the intent you set the flag.

Comment: it worked!  I didn't paid attention to that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that any prerequisites required (you really can't get prerequisites that aren't requried though ;) ) are loaded before the application loads.  For example if it requires JRE as it is Android.

Comment: Umm how do I check that?